# How to weight probabilites of getting sampled depending on the frequency of occurrence?

Tags: sampling, random-generation, sample-weighting

Unfortunately I'm struggling to describe my problem mathematically. I have 2000 strings, many of which are repeated. Now I want to write a 'random' sampling algorithm that produces 100 samples out of the 2000 but in a way that every string in the sample set is represented 'fairly'. For example, if a string occurs 10 times in the population, its probability of getting sampled should be reduced so that other non-repeated strings have more chance to get sampled. In other words, I need to weight all probabilities depending on their frequency of occurrence in the population. The sum of all these 2000 weighted probabilities should be 1. can anyone help me to describe this problem in a mathematical manner? which approach is suitable for solving this task?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not just find the set of unique strings and then sample uniformly from them ?

Comment: If I sort out only unit strings, the population size may become lower than the desired sample size. I thought I could solve this issue by weighting the probabilities.

Comment: Assign each item a weight 1/N, where N is the number of repetitions, then divide each item's weight by the sum of weights?